# Multiple Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to use docker and want to create an Ubuntu base with three containers that do the following:

1. Container: Install Wildfly
2. Container: Install MySQL
3. Container: Other Required Packages

Does that mean, I have to create three Dockerfiles in three different directories containing each the following top line?:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orchestrate the containers with `docker-compose`

1- Create `docker-compose.yml`

2- Inside define:

```
version: '3'
services:
  wildly:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Wildfly
  mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Mysql
  anotherpackages:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_AnotherPackages
```

it is not always the case that you need to write a docker file, for example for the database service you can simply pull the image from the docker hub and use it directly. 
something like below

```
db:
    image: mysql
```

3- Create files and both define commands you prefer:

```
Dockerfile_Wildfly
 FROM wildfly

Dockerfile_Mysql
 FROM mariadb

Dockerfile_AnotherPackages
 FROM node
 FROM nginx
```

Comment: I went through same problem. So I share the solution. Very grateful for the vote. I'm glad it was resolved

Answer (score 4):

You can have more than one Dockerfile in the same directory if desired. To specify the Dockerfile to use, use the -f argument, e.g

```
docker build -f wildfly.Dockerfile ./wildfly
docker build -f mysql.Dockerfile ./mysql
docker build -f other.Dockerfile ./other
```

In Compose, these arguments correspond to the `dockerfile` and `context` properties.

It is not always the case that you need to write a docker file, for example for the database service you can simply pull the image from the docker hub and use it directly. 
something like below

```
db:
    image: mysql
```

You can, of course, have them share the same context, e.g.

```
docker build -f wildfly.Dockerfile .
docker build -f mysql.Dockerfile .
docker build -f other.Dockerfile .
```

Just be aware that the context is sent in full to the daemon (respecting .dockerignore) so this might lead to longer build times if there is a lot of redundant data.

If there is a lot of reuse between the Dockerfiles, you can even have all of them in one file, e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as base
...
FROM base AS wildfly
(install wildfly)

FROM base AS mysql
(install mysql)
...
```

Then you can build the specific image with e.g.

```
docker build --target wildfly  .
```

In Compose, these arguments correspond to the `target` and `context` properties.

This is called multi-stage builds, and is not always a good idea but is sometimes helpful to mitigate Docker's lack of support for #include.

Answer (score 2):

You can create many Dockerfile and precise their name in the build command as suggested in another answer (@Krumelur's answer), but you can also use docker compose by calling directly the image from docker.io (if the base image for those dependecies in the hub match your neeed)

In this way you dont need any Dockerfile at all.

It should looks like this :

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  wildfly:
    #this image will be automatically downloaded from your registry (by default Docker hub)
    image: jboss/wildfly 
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '9990:9990'
    volumes:
      - 'wildfly_data:/wildfly_data'
    environment:
      - WILDFLY_PASSWORD=password
  mysql:
    #this image will be automatically downloaded from your registry (by default Docker hub)
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  otherService :
    image: busybox


volumes:
  my-db:
  wildfly_data:
```

Then you just need to call the command : `docker-compose up`

Comment: I think the OP builds his own images from Dockerfiles

Comment: @Krumelur : he asks "Does that mean, I have to create three Dockerfiles in three different directories containing each the following top line?"....my answer is : "No that does not mean you have to create three Dockerfiles....you can directly call the base image from the hub if you do not want to modify them.

Comment: Fair point, I didn't read it like that, but it also makes sense.

Comment: Actually @Krumelur was right that I wanted to create the Dockerfiles from scratch and not load them from the Hub. Many thanks for your answers.